# How to upload multiple images to a folder using ajax php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images to a folder at a time by using AJAX, JQuery, and PHP. The code is running for single file upload but not running for multiple image upload.
 If I am uploading a single image without loop then its working fine but in case of loop it's not working.

I am using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload Iamge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#but_upload").click(function(){
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    //following  code is working fine in for single image upload
                    // var files = $('#file')[0].files[0]; 
                    // fd.append('file',files);

                    //this code not working for multiple image upload           
                    var names = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < $('#file').get(0).files.length; ++i) {
                        names.push($('#file').get(0).files[i].name);
                    }
                    fd.append('file[]',names);

                    /*var ins = document.getElementById('file').files.length;
                    for (var x = 0; x <ins; x++) {
                        fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[x]);
                    }*/

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'upload.php',
                        type:'post',
                        data:fd,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(response){
                            if(response != 0){
                                $("#img").attr("src",response);
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(response){
                            alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    //HTML Part

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>AJAX File upload</h1>
            <form method="post" action=""  id="myform">
                <div>
                    <img src="" id="img" width="100" height="100">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  multiple="multiple" />
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" 
        id="but_upload">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

//PHP Code 

<?php
    /* Getting file name */
    echo "<script>alert('yes');</script>";
    //without loop working fine
    $count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        /* Location */
        $location = "upload/".$filename;
        /* Upload file */
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
            echo $location;
        } else {
            echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload Iamge</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#but_upload").click(function(){
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    //following  code is working fine in for single image upload
                    // var files = $('#file')[0].files[0]; 
                    // fd.append('file',files);

                    //this code not working for multiple image upload           
                    var names = [];
                    var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files; 
                    // for multiple files
                    for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
                        fd.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
                    }
                    fd.append('file[]',names);

                    /*var ins = document.getElementById('file').files.length;
                    for (var x = 0; x <ins; x++) {
                        fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[x]);
                    }*/

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'upload.php',
                        type:'post',
                        data:fd,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(response){
                            if(response != 0){
                                $("#img").attr("src",response);
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(response){
                            alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    //HTML Part

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>AJAX File upload</h1>
            <form method="post" action=""  id="myform">
                <div>
                    <img src="" id="img" width="100" height="100">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  multiple="multiple" />
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" 
        id="but_upload">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

have made changes in below code

```
var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files; // for multiple files
    for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
    fd.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
}
fd.append('file[]',names);
```

And there are also changes in PHP code

```
<?php
/* Getting file name */
//without loop working fine

    $count = count($_FILES);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $filename = $_FILES['file_'.$i];
        /* Location */
        echo $location = "upload/".$filename['name'];
        /* Upload file */
        if(move_uploaded_file($filename['tmp_name'],$location)){
            echo $location;
        } else {
            echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

count of files and file name are comming in a different way so I have made the changes as required instead of if gives file array like `$_FILE['file_0']`,`$_FILE['file_1']` and so on, **I have also change the permission of upload directory please check if your directory have read and write permission (777) or not**, this code works for me you can try I hope it will work for you also :-)

Comment: is there any error or something, use error_reporting(-1); ini_set("display_errors", true) in you php page and check in console for errors

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you will need to add `index` of particular file

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$location); // $i is index
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the current answer, as I couldn't get it to work in my current implementation, so I'll post another answer that worked in my situation.

I'll give the file name, relevant code, and then a summary of important notes for each file.

---

form.html

```
<form class='myForm' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='myFileInput[]' multiple>
    <button class='mySubmitButton'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

First, it's important to point out that the form element's `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is REQUIRED when submitting a file. You should also name your file inputs as an array (notice the name of my input is **myFileInput[]** and not **myFileInput** without the square brackets. This will make sure to POST your files as an array, not as an object!

You'll also notice I don't use an `<input type='submit'>`. This is just personal preference, since I don't have to prevent default submit behavior and can just as easily target the element for a `click` listener later on.

---

form.js

```
$('.mySubmitButton').click(async function() {
    let formData = new FormData($('.myForm')[0]);

    let myAjax = $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form.php'
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData
        }
    );
});
```

That easy! Just make sure when you target your `form` element via jQuery, you get the first index (`$('.myForm')[0]`) to get the DOM element, and not the jQuery object. I use an async function here because in my tiny asynchronous brain, that makes more sense to me, and callbacks and promises scare me, but you can easily use the `success/failure` members of the `$.ajax` object, or the `.done()` methods.

---

form.php

```
if (myPostSubmitCondition) {
    //check upload errors, (PLEASE) do server side validation, etc.
    for (var $f = 0; $f < count($_FILES['myFileInput']['name']); $f++) {
        $uploadedFile = array(
            'name' => $_FILES['myFileInput']['name'][$f],
            'type' => $_FILES['myFileInput']['type'][$f],
            'tmp_name' => $_FILES['myFileInput']['tpm_name'][$f],
            'error' => $_FILES['myFileInput']['error'][$f],
            'size' => $_FILES['myFileInput']['size'][$f]
        ); //I just do this to make my life easier, since the $_FILES global has a weird structure
        
        //do other file stuff here
        
        if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
            //handle errors here
        )
    }
}
```

<Insert mandatory warning about over-simplification, and neglect of server-side verification (including MIME types!) here>

---

That's it! This should work for both single file and multi-file uploads.